# How to bring up the merge tool to resolve conflicts in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 17.7 and when I tried to merge a branch to my branch, I got a 'Merge completed with conflicts...' message.
In the 'Unmerged Changes' section shown below, I choose the Compare option and I get a compare window with two panes, one for the incoming version and one for my local version and it shows the differences. I am used to the one with the 3 panes and the ability to select what sections to merge and commit the merge.

How does one get the merge tool to show instead of the compare tool?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-resolve-conflicts?view=vs-2022#resolve-merge-conflicts), you should be able to click the gear icon and change it to "Vertical View" to achieve what you want.  Double click one of the files in the unmerged changes section and then look for the gear icon in the merge editor:

[image: gear icon and vertical view option]

This should result in the 3 way merge option you speak of:

[image: 3 way merge image]

Comment: That view is when you're already in the merge tool and that gear is only for changing the layout in the merge tool. It has nothing to do with getting into the merge tool which my question is about.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich the documentation states *"To start resolving conflicts, **double-click a file**. Or if you have a file with conflicts opened in the editor, you can select **Open Merge Editor**"* - is that all you mean then? Double clicking the file should open the editor

Comment: Double clicking the file opens the compare tool. It does not open the merge tool. In other situations I get the merge tool. It seems this is somehow related to the current file whether it has been committed or not or it's staged or not. I need to find out what the pattern is.