# Unable to find 'Resolve Conflicts' window in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.3.4 and trying to find 'Resolve Conflicts Window'.  On merging Git master into branch, I get a message, "Merge completed with conflicts..."Resolve the conflicts" and commit results.
However, when I click on "Resolve Conflicts", Git Changes window appears but there are no options to merge. Double clicking on file opens a compare window and does NOT open a merge window. Any suggestions.

SO answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76863825/how-to-bring-up-the-merge-tool-to-resolve-conflicts-in-visual-studio-2022) didn’t help.

Resolve Conflicts Window

[image: resolve conflicts window]

Here' my Visual Studio settings ( if that helps)
[image: vs settings]

Comment: What is `git status` telling you?

Comment: Says I am on branch CUP1258. Your branch is up to date with 'origin/CUP1258' and shows that I have changes (4 files) to be committed.

Comment: I would inspect those four files manually (just look at them in a text editor) to see if you see [merge conflict marks](https://dev.to/smitterhane/uncanny-visual-symbols-of-a-git-conflict-explained-568p). Also you could use the diff command in a terminal to see what that tells you (I think you will need to do `git diff --staged`).

Comment: Its hard to describe what do do visually in VS by clicking things because ... its visual and its about clicking things. I think if you get past this problem you'll probably start to learn the visual tools as you begin to use them more often. We don't really know what you are seeing (unless its seeing your VS git global settings cuz you did show us that!)

Comment: Interestingly the fact that you don't have a message from git status about merge conflicts - there may not really be any. So look at the files - if they are correct (if you can determine this) just commit them. Or unstage the commits and start from there. You should in fact also be able to see what's changed on these staged commits ... so you should have lots of info to work with here.

Answer (score 0):

Spent some time playing with it and finally could resolve issue.
I had 2 **new** files in my branch which I believe were preventing 'Resolve Conflicts' editor from appearing. I checked in the branch first ( including new files) and then merged master into branch. That did the trick. Merge prompted a window to 'Resolve the Conflicts', and clicking it allowed me to merge files.